# How may I run fisher.test within ddply?

Tags: r, plyr, chi-squared

```
d <- data.frame(topic=c("a","a","a","b","c","c"), year=c(2001,2002,2004,2003,2011,2012),
                I=c(3,2,4,3,0,1), II=c(2,1,2,3,4,0), III=c(0,0,1,2,3,0))
library(plyr)
chip <- ddply(df.agg[,-2], "topic", function(x){
    round(fisher.test(x[,-1])$p.value, 3)
  })
#Error in fisher.test(x[, -1]) : 'x' must have at least 2 rows and columns
```

how can I make `fisher.test` within ddply? I want topics with one row (such as `b`) have `NA` value, but the other rows report `p` value.

Comment: Is `df.agg[,-2]` supposed to be `d` or `d[,-2]`?

Comment: yes, I am sorry for the mistake.

Comment: The error message pretty much explains it. You need at least two rows and columns for it to work, but there is only one row where `topic` is `b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in base R with `split` and `sapply`:

```
sapply(split(d, d$topic), function(i) 

  if (nrow(i) == 1) {

    NA

  } else {

    round(fisher.test(i[,3:5])$p.value, 3)

})
```

Result:

```
    a     b     c 
1.000    NA 0.125
```